# Many different hosts in Ingress configuration file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I am trying to automate the hosts in Ingress Controller and I'm facing the problem of generating many hosts into one file. What I mean is, I have this ingress.yaml:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-host
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: a
spec:
  rules:
  - host: a.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: a
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: b.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: b
            port:
              number: 80
  ...
  - host: x.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: x
            port:
              number: 80
...
```

in this example I have multiple instances: `a`, `b`, all the way to `x` and I anticipate a lot more. Right now I am programmatically regenerating the whole ingress.yaml to add/remove certain hosts. This is prone to errors and hard to maintain, as I must constantly be aware about `ingress.yaml` to be broken for one reason or another.

What would really help me is to put every `host` into a separate file and (maybe) just tell `ingress.yaml` to scan the whole directory where those files are to be stored. This way, I can just add/remove a single file and reload Ingress

Is there an option for that? I found somewhere that `IngressSpec` could be somehow defined, but I do not see any usefull link with a valid example. Maybe someone found a solution to that already and can point me to the right direction?

Comment: You can create multiple ingress objects. It's common to install them along with your service rather than a single file like this.

Comment: @jordanm what about traffic? Does kubernetes iterate over each ingress object to find the correct host?

Comment: The nginx ingress controller uses all the ingress objects to generate the nginx config for the nginx pods that ingest the traffic. Different ingress controllers will work differently.

Comment: Oh, I see, the problem is the terminology: `Ingress` vs `IngressController`. Thank you for this insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jordanm suggested in the comment, I went with multiple Ingress objects on one `IngressController`, being sure I get rid of `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend` annotation:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-x-host
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: x.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: x
            port:
              number: 80
```

I generate a unique file for each of hosts, replacing `x` with my unique name.

I also have to make sure that `metadata.name` is unique. If `metadata.name` is the same for every object, then it just gets replaced as I `apply` the new configuration. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

[Hostname wildcards](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards)

> Hosts can be precise matches (for example “foo.bar.com”) or a wildcard (for example “*.foo.com”).

Or use template system, such as [helm](https://helm.sh/) or Kustomize

Comment: wildcards will not work, as I have a unique instance per host. And helm or kustomize will require the same backend programming, but just for another layer of abstraction. It's more convenient to go with what @jordanm suggested.